# Problems deserializing long JSON strings with JSON.NET

Tags: c#, .net, json, windows-phone, json.net

I am building a cache system for my app, that saves all received JSON data in a  `Dictionary<string, CacheWrapper>` object, where the key (string) is the REST-url asked for data (i.e. www.dataapi.com/events/28127.json)

The `CacheWrapper` class:

```
class CacheWrapper {
  object cachedObject { get; set; }
  DateTime expires { get; set; }
  public isValid() { /*...*/ }
}
```

When the app shuts down, this (potentially) very large data structure is serialized with JSON.net and written to file. **This all works fine.** The problem comes after a few days of use, when the user have accumulated a large amount of data (let's say 2-3 MB of JSON data). When I try to deserialize this, JSON.net throws a `JsonReaderException` - and I suspect it's because of the sheer size of it all. With smaller amounts of data, this works just fine.

Are there any limitations when it comes to size of the JSON string given to `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json)`? Could there be other reasons? As far as I know, the JSON produced is valid (I tested it on ~ 1.5 mb of data, and that passed the validator).

**Update:**

I tried to abuse my app as much as possible, and ended up with a 6 million character string of JSON (~12 mb). For some reason, this works fine. So size isn't an issue it seems. The `JsonReaderException` I got earlier mentioned there was an issue during deserialization of the JSON (probably illegal json then..), but that itself is pretty weird, given that I use JSON.net for both serialization and deserialization of this data. This keeps getting weirder. I will keep on testing throughout the day and mention my findings here.

Comment: 2-3MB of data is quite small now-a-days. Have you tried this with the same volume of data that the users system will grow to. If not then I would suggest doing this first to eliminate volume as the problem.

Comment: I have used my app very continuously for about 48 hours. The maximum cache period is 24 hours, so the data amount won't get a lot bigger than this. It might not be a large amount of data, but it's a somewhat large object to deserialize in one piece :-)

Comment: Instead of storing the entire Cache in one file it might be better to split the data into contiguous chunks based on usage and store them in separate files. Basically implement a storage strategy.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [.NET DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx) 
 
It is much more flexible and powerful, and allows you to work with streams if they are available.

Comment: Tried using that - but as far as I've understood, it doesn't support serializing or deserializing Dictionary-objects.